# multiple='multiple' for <select> is not working

Tags: html

I m working on a application for mail sending and need to use select tag of HTML with showing multiple options (But select only one at a time).

I tried `multiple='multiple'` but it is showing only one option and arrow disappears form select box.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
                                  <option>Volvo</option>
                                  <option>Saab</option>
                                  <option>Mercedes</option>
                                  <option>Audi</option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: Do you see the same error at http://jsfiddle.net/x4vMb/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to include a "size" in addition to the "multiple" attribute, in order to show more than one option at a time. Try something like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="...">...</option>
  ...
</select>
```

As an alternative, since you want only one option selectable, you could consider using a list of [radio buttons](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm). For example,

```
<input type="radio" name="auto" value="Audi" />Audi<br />
<input type="radio" name="auto" value="Honda" />Honda<br />
...
```

Comment: @AshokYadav, what browser are you using, and have you tried it in any others?

Comment: @AshokYadav, it works as you'd like for me in Firefox. Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: @imm - since when is radio button an alternative for multiple select? I think, checkbox is the right answer. edit: OK, sorry, I read now the whole original post.

Comment: @shaggy, OP requests that user should be able to see many options, but select only one.

Comment: Radio button is not suited here because i do not have limitation of options. These will be Subjects for emails that will be picked from database.