# <select> multiple="multiple" not working in Firefox

Tags: html, jsp

This problem appears only in Firefox (I'm using the latest version 26.0), it works fine in IE and Chrome. `<select>` tag is not showing the values, but it works fine if I select any of the blanks, so I guess the problem is in presentation somewhere. I tried adding `size` attribute like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858295/multiple-multiple-for-select-is-not-working), but it didn't work.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="activity.teachers" >
    <option>Select</option>
    <c:forEach var="theTeacher" items="${teacherList}">
        <option value="${theTeacher.teacherId}" label="${theTeacher.title.titleDescription} ${theTeacher.firstName} ${theTeacher.lastName}" />
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

It looks like this in Firefox:

[image]

And it's suppose to look like this (IE/Chrome):

[image]

Help?

Update: This is HTML page

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="activity.teachers" >
    <option>Select</option>     
    <option value="1" label="PhD Tom Hale" />       
    <option value="2" label="MSc Jane Briggs" />
    <option value="3" label="PhD Steve McClintock" />
</select>
```

Comment: Have you checked the rendered html with view source in FF?  Are the options there?

Comment: just so you know, unless you're using XHTML or some other strict doctype, it is fine to have just `multiple`, you don't need the `="multiple"` part

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes, the values are there, I've updated my post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label attribute is not supported in FF.  Change it to this:

```
<option value="${theTeacher.teacherId}">${theTeacher.title.titleDescription} ${theTeacher.firstName} ${theTeacher.lastName}</option>
```

[Unfixed bug for this issue open since 2000](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40545)

Comment: I wasn't even aware the `label` was a thing for `option` tags, only for `optgroup`...

Answer (score 0):

I've got a problem also that i've got specified "size=1" and in Chrome it works just fine. But in Firefox it in one line select box.. Simple change it to size="5" and it works.